# Find next empty row for automatic data entry from excel userform

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

NextRow = 2

Sheets("data").Cells(NextRow, 2) = Now

Sheets("data").Cells(NextRow, 3) = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(NextRow, 2)

Sheets("data").Cells(NextRow, 4) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b3")

Sheets("data").Cells(NextRow, 5) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b4")

Sheets("data").Cells(NextRow, 6) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b5")

Sheets("data").Cells(NextRow, 7) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b6")

Sheets("data").Cells(NextRow, 8) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b7")

Sheets("data").Cells(NextRow, 9) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b8")

Sheets("data").Cells(NextRow, 10) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b10")

Sheets("data").Cells(NextRow, 11) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b11")

Sheets("data").Cells(NextRow, 12) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b12")
End Sub
```

Here is my code. Whenever I keep on giving value it overrides. How to change it? How to make entry in seperate row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pop a little loop in to discover the next empty row, for example (untested!):

```
NextRow=2
do until Sheets("data").Cells(NextRow,2) = ""
    NextRow = NextRow + 1
Loop
```